# Can't find the source of Run-time check failure #2

Tags: c++, arrays

I have two problems with my code that are driving me nuts to complete.

First is a "Run-time check failure #2. Stack around the variable 'grade' was corrupted"

From what I have found, this is an error when something is printed outside the bounds of an array.  I have looked and double checked all the code and fixed some possible problems, but I can't find the last one that trips this code.

Second, with the name array, why does it show the first letter of the next line?  It is not in the locals showing the extra character but it still prints that way.  I can't seem to find a good fix.

EDIT:  I fixed the Switch statement to just 10,9,8,7,6 tests and deleted the unneeded lines.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<array>
using namespace std;

void outPut ( double score[][6], char name[][10], char grade[11]);
void dataIn ( double score[][6] ,char name[][10]);
void grades ( double score[][6], char grade[11] );

int main ( )
{
    double score[11][6];
    char name[11][10], grade[11];
    for (int q = 0;q < 12;q++)
        for (int w = 0;w < 7;w++)
            score[q][w] = 0;
    for (int z = 0;z < 12;z++)
        for (int x = 0;x < 10;x++)
            name[z][x] = 0;
    dataIn ( score, name );
    grades ( score, grade );
    outPut ( score, name, grade );
    system ( "pause" );
}

void outPut (double score[][6], char name[][10], char grade[11] )
{
    cout << endl;
    for (int a = 0;a < 11;a++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 11;c++)
            cout << name[a][c] << " ";
        cout << setw ( 6 );
        cout << showpoint << fixed << setprecision ( 2 );
        for (int b = 0; b < 6;b++)
            cout << score[a][b] << " ";
        cout << grade[a];
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void dataIn ( double score[][6],char name[][10] )
{
    ifstream inData;
    ifstream inData1;
    inData1.open ( "inName.txt" );
    inData.open ( "indata.txt" );
    for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++)
        inData1 >> name[j], 11;
    for (int row = 0; row < 11;row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < 5;col++)
            inData >> score[row][col];
}

void grades ( double score[][6], char grade[11] ) //[row][column]
{
    double sum = 0, sum1 = 0, avg, avg1;
    int avg2;
    for (int a = 0;a < 11;a++)
    {
        sum1 = 0;
        for (int b = 0;b < 6;b++)
            sum1 = sum1 + score[a][b];
        avg = sum1 / 5;
        score[a][5] = avg;
    }
    for (int b = 0;b < 11;b++)
        sum = sum + score[b][6];        
    avg1 = sum / 10;
    score[10][5] = avg1;
    for (int q = 0;q < 12;q++)
    {
        avg2 = score[q][5];
        switch (avg2)
        {
            case 100:
            case 99:
            case 98:
            case 97:
            case 96:
            case 95:
            case 94:
            case 93:
            case 92:
            case 91:
            case 90:
                grade[q] = 'A';
                break;
            case 89:
            case 88:
            case 87:
            case 86:
            case 85:
            case 84:
            case 83:
            case 82:
            case 81:
            case 80:
                grade[q] = 'B';
                break;
            case 79:
            case 78:
            case 77:
            case 76:
            case 75:
            case 74:
            case 73:
            case 72:
            case 71:
            case 70:
                grade[q] = 'C';
                break;
            case 69:
            case 68:
            case 67:
            case 66:
            case 65:
            case 64:
            case 63:
            case 62:
            case 61:
            case 60:
                grade[q] = 'D';
                break;
            default:
                grade[q] = 'F';
        }
    }
}
```

inName.txt:

```
Johnson
Aniston
Cooper
Gupta
Blair
Clark
Kennedy
Bronson
Sunny
Smith
Average
```

inData.txt

```
85 83 77 91 76 
80 90 95 93 48  
78 81 11 90 73  
92 83 30 69 87  
23 45 96 38 59  
60 85 45 39 67  
77 31 52 74 83  
93 94 89 77 97  
79 85 28 93 82  
85 72 49 75 63
```

Output of the code

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I went through your code and it's filled with indexing errors. Many loops use upper limit that's more than size of corresponding array. Examples are present in the `main()` function: `q < 12`, `w < 7`, `z < 12` and these will write outside the allowed bounds of given arrays. There are no code checks at all for this, and when you write over the bound, it will not necessarily throw run-time error as it happens, instead the error is usually shown when the memory outside the array is ***accessed for use***. It's important to understand the memory layout of a C or C++ program. Each function has a stack, and value-types are completely stored on the stack (like arrays). So when you write outside the boundary of an array, you're corrupting the stack. That's actually how buffer overflow attacks are performed, by writing outside the allowed boundaries and overwriting `return pointer` value.

Anyway, I have went through your code and managed to fix the issues:

In `main()`:

```
for (int q = 0;q < 11;q++)
    for (int w = 0;w < 6;w++)
        score[q][w] = 0;
for (int z = 0;z < 11;z++)
    for (int x = 0;x < 10;x++)
```

In `dataIn(...)`:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) 
    inData1 >> name[j], 11;
for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
    for (int col = 0; col < 5;col++)
```

In `grades(...)`:

```
for (int a = 0;a < 10;a++)
{
    sum1 = 0;
    for (int b = 0;b < 5;b++)
        sum1 = sum1 + score[a][b];
    avg = sum1 / 5;
    score[a][5] = avg;
}
/* code between */
for (int b = 0;b < 10;b++)
    sum = sum + score[b][5]; 
/* code between */
for (int q = 0;q < 11;q++)
```

And last, but not least, to fix your SECOND problem...

In `outPut(...)`:

```
for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
```

It's important to understand index of arrays in C++. An array of `size = 10` is indexed between `[0-9]` and `10` is outside the boundary of the array. That caused all of your issues.

I would recommend that you set the values `11, 10 and 6` as constants defined in the beginning of the file, for example:

```
#define I_COUNT 11 // number of instances
#define N_WIDTH 10 // name size
#define G_COUNT 6  // number of grades (including average for instance)
```

Then use constants for loops instead of numbers:

```
double score[I_COUNT][G_COUNT];
```

That way you can easily change the code to include more instances and grades. And you won't have such errors.

---

Alternatively, I have written a program using `std::vector` to do what you're doing in a much cleaner way. And I have also made it compute averages for each subject. `inName.txt` must remove `Average` from the last entry (just designed it this way). It can accept any number of instances (people names) and their corresponding grades. Grades can also be more than 5 if you wish. But they must be consistent (same number in each row).

Here is the code with comments:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

// type aliases - just to make it easier to read
using Names = std::vector<std::string>;
using Grades = std::vector<std::vector<double>>;
using GradeLetters = std::vector<char>;
char get_grade_letter(double avg);

// function prototypes
Names read_names(const std::string& path);
Grades read_grades(const std::string& path);
GradeLetters calculate_averages(Grades& grades);
void print_out(const Names& names, const Grades& grades, const GradeLetters& grade_letters);

int main()
{
  auto names = read_names("inName.txt");
  auto grades = read_grades("inData.txt");

  auto grade_letters = calculate_averages(grades);
  print_out(names, grades, grade_letters);

  return 0; // don't forget this
}

// takes file-path input, reads content and returns vector of strings 
Names read_names(const std::string& path) {
  std::ifstream in(path); 
  std::vector<std::string> names; 
  std::string name;
  while (std::getline(in, name)) {
    if (name != "") // in case there is empty line in the end
      names.push_back(name);
  }
  names.push_back("Average"); // let the program add it instead of having it in file
  return names; 
}

// takes file-path input, reads grades and stores them in matrix-ish format
Grades read_grades(const std::string& path) {
  std::ifstream in(path);
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> grades;
  std::string grade_line;
  while (std::getline(in, grade_line)) {
    std::stringstream ss(grade_line);
    std::vector<double> p_grades;
    double grade;
    while (ss >> grade) 
      p_grades.push_back(grade);
    grades.push_back(p_grades);
  }
  return grades;
}

// calculates averages (per instance, and overall) - returns letter grades vector
GradeLetters calculate_averages(Grades& grades) {
  std::vector<char> grade_letters; 
  std::vector<double> averages;    // seperate vector, not yet in grades

  int grades_per_instance = grades.at(0).size(); // for avg calc
  averages.resize(grades_per_instance + 1); // +1 for the average

  for (size_t i = 0; i < grades.size(); i++) {
    double i_sum = 0; // instance sum 
    for (size_t j = 0; j < grades[i].size(); j++) {
      i_sum += grades[i][j];
      averages[j] += grades[i][j]; /* sum for each subject, for all students 
                                    * average of this will be calculated in 
                                    * a seperate loop, see below */
    }
    double i_avg = i_sum / grades_per_instance;
    grades[i].push_back(i_avg);

    char grade_letter = get_grade_letter(i_avg);
    grade_letters.push_back(grade_letter);
  }

  int total_instances = grades.size();
  double all_sum = 0; // for average of averages
  for (size_t i = 0; i < averages.size(); i++) {
    averages[i] /= total_instances; // can't do this in first loop, it must be over before we do it
    all_sum += averages[i];
  }
  double all_avg = all_sum / grades_per_instance;
  averages[averages.size() - 1] = all_avg; // averages is now complete, add it to `grades`
  grades.push_back(averages); // we did not add averages row until now

  char all_avg_grade_letter = get_grade_letter(all_avg); 
  grade_letters.push_back(all_avg_grade_letter);

  return grade_letters;
}

char get_grade_letter(double avg) {
  int avg_simplified = (int)(avg / 10);
  switch (avg_simplified)
  {
  case 10:
  case 9:
    return 'A'; // [90-100]
  case 8:
    return 'B'; // [80-90[
  case 7:
    return 'C'; // [70-80[
  case 6:
    return 'D'; // [60-70[
  default:
    return 'F'; // <60 || >100
  }
}

void print_out(const Names& names, const Grades& grades, const GradeLetters& grade_letters) {
  std::cout << std::showpoint << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2); // can be set just once

  // print header
  std::cout << std::setw(20) << std::left << "Name:" << '\t'; 
  for (size_t i = 0; i < grades.at(0).size() - 1; i++)
    std::cout << "Sub" << i << "   "; 
  std::cout << std::setw(5) << "Avg" << "  Letter" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;

  // print content
  for (size_t i = 0; i < grades.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << std::setw(20) << std::left << names.at(i) << '\t';
    for (size_t j = 0; j < grades.at(i).size(); j++)
      std::cout << std::setw(5) << grades.at(i).at(j) << "  ";
    std::cout << grade_letters.at(i) << std::endl;
    if(i ==  grades.size()-2)
      std::cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Name:                   Sub0   Sub1   Sub2   Sub3   Sub4   Avg    Letter
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Johnson                 85.00  83.00  77.00  91.00  76.00  82.40  B
Aniston                 80.00  90.00  95.00  93.00  48.00  81.20  B
Cooper                  78.00  81.00  11.00  90.00  73.00  66.60  D
Gupta                   92.00  83.00  30.00  69.00  87.00  72.20  C
Blair                   23.00  45.00  96.00  38.00  59.00  52.20  F
Clark                   60.00  85.00  45.00  39.00  67.00  59.20  F
Kennedy                 77.00  31.00  52.00  74.00  83.00  63.40  D
Bronson                 93.00  94.00  89.00  77.00  97.00  90.00  A
Sunny                   79.00  85.00  28.00  93.00  82.00  73.40  C
Smith                   85.00  72.00  49.00  75.00  63.00  68.80  D
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Average                 75.20  74.90  57.20  73.90  73.50  70.94  C
```

Comment: WOW!! Thank you for the help.  It looks like I misunderstood the book.  I like how your full code looks and I understand most of it.  It is a little past what I am doing but I like the way it looks and how its formatted.

Comment: @JeffA I am glad to help. Feel free to use any of the provided code. I thought of having an example of the same thing using `std::vector` which is much better than arrays (largely because you would never get stack-overflow error with them).

Comment: I submitted the work but I overlooked one thing and it looks good.  Now I need to rewrite to get all input data in the same file.